# How to add a Blazor Page to an existing .NET MAUI application

Tags: blazor, maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

If you have an existing .NET MAUI application/project (Xaml) and want to add a Blazor Page to it, what steps would be needed to get it working? Have  tried using the steps described here but there seem to be more that is needed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview

While the main question is about adding Blazor pages to an existing MAUI project, for simplicity, let's assume you have a just created a new .NET MAUI project in VS2022 and would like to add the typical Counter Blazor page that is generated by most VS2022 templates and get it up an running.

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

As this is an existing project, just using the .NET MAUI Blazor template most likely isn't an option here unless you move everything not Blazor over to the new project.

Thanks.

Comment: May I know if you are going to build a new NET MAUI Blazor app?

Comment: Not in this particular case/project unless it turns out to be impossible to add Blazor to an already existing project.

Comment: You may refer to  relevant contents of the  . Net MAUI Blazor application , and then try to import relevant dependency packages into the MAUI application.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?  I have now come across the need to add a BlazorWebView to my existing MAUI Native app.